# How can i display Google maps based on lat and lang and place in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, android-mapview

I want display Google maps in the Android Based on the user edit text value lat and lang and place name and then i finally click on the search button the maps was displayed in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create some object  like.

```
MapView mapView; 
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
String add = "";
double lattitude ;
double longitude;
```

Searching location by Name and show Maps.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Search Location");
        alert.setMessage("Enter Location Name: ");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();
          // Do something with value!
          Log.d("value", value);

          Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());    
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
                    value, 5);
                String add = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    p = new GeoPoint(
                            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
                    mc.animateTo(p);    
                    mapView.invalidate();
                }    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
          }
        });

        alert.show();

    }
```

Searching location by Entering Latitude and Longitude and show map..

```
    searchUsingLangLat()
    {       

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);            
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.latlong, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Search Location");
        alert.setMessage("Enter Lattitude and Longitude: ");

        alert.setView(textEntryView); 
        // Set an EditText view to get user input
        AlertDialog latLongPrompt = alert.create();

        final EditText lat = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.lat);
        final EditText longi = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.longi);
    //alert.setView(lat);
        //alert.setView(longi);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "clicked ok ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(lat.getText().toString());
          Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(longi.getText().toString());
          // Do something with value!
         // Log.d("value1", value1);
          //Log.d("value2", value2);

          p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (value1 * 1E6), 
                    (int) (value2 * 1E6));

                mc.animateTo(p);
                mc.setZoom(17); 
                mapView.invalidate();


          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
          }
        });

        alert.show();
```

And finally you need to show map. write following code in onCreate() method.

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.setCenter(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 

    //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);      


    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
```

Try this code...if you get any error free to ask.

Comment: Hi sandip can i place all these code in one single Activity ?

Comment: i entered search place and i press ok the place is not show in the map?

Comment: yes you need to place all code in one activity... which error you getting?

Comment: ok thanks for ur reply i am getting the alert box enter search place i was give the nework. it canot show in the maps i canot put the else block in my Activity ?

Comment: kk. check my updated answer.... use searchUsingLangLat() method instead of else block.

Comment: i didn't get the place in the map now also first launch screen is coming with alert i entered some name it not show in the map i want show that place in map?

Comment: come on to chat room... on AndroidDeskhelp chat room

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10918/discussion-between-user1365148-and-sandip-armal)

Comment: my need is i am getting the alert dialog i was given the place it cannot  show in the map how can i achive that ?

Comment: when i click on the one place in the map it give the dialog box where you want save like i can select one of the are from regions like favorites the place is moved to that Android listplace

Comment: how can i display favorites list in the Android listview ?

Answer (score 0):

If you store the Latitude and Longitude of a bunch of locations in a SQLite Database, You could retrieve these values and place them each in an OverlayItem class for use in Google's Map code!!

1. Database name: database
2. Table name: place

Fields in place Table:

1. id
   title
   description
   latitude
   longitude

You would want to do a query like this:

```
SELECT title, description, latitude, longitude
FROM place
```

Which can be done in Android like this:

```
    // get your database object here using your DbHelper object and the
    // method getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Cursor locationCursor = databaseObject.query("place", new String[] {
            "title", "description", "latitude", "longitude" }, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    locationCursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String title = locationCursor.String(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("title"));
        String description = locationCursor.String(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("description"));
        int latitude = (int) (locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("latitude")) * 1E6);
        int longitude = (int) (locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                .getColumnIndex("longitude")) * 1E6);

        items.add(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), title,
                description));
    } while (locationCursor.moveToNext());
```

You need to times the double values by 1e6 because Android uses an integer representation of the lat/long values. If you already took care of this when populating the database, skip the multiplication and use locationCursor.getInt(...).

Comment: Thanks for ur Reply how can i give dialog box when i clik on the once place in the map are u want save this as Favorites? then we show this place in Favorotes Listview in Android ?

Comment: You can use a boolean fields in your database that's by default set to faulse, when a place is marked favorite you set thet boolean to true and after that you can query your database to get all places marked favorite by checking this boolean value!! Please accept the first answer

Comment: when i click the place in the map it shows the alert dialog box having fav and Business when i am click one it goes that coressponding list please help ?